# Plugin not able to install

Tags: plugins

Trying to install the redactor plugin through the plugin store throws the following error

Error: curl error 28 while downloading https://composer.craftcms.com/packages.json: Resolving timed out after 10000 milliseconds

Composer output: Loading composer repositories with package information
A connection timeout was encountered. If you intend to run Composer without connecting to the internet, run the command again prefixed with COMPOSER_DISABLE_NETWORK=1 to make Composer run in offline mode.

I installed craft cms it through docker and all permission got provided. Does anyone help me to troubleshoot this?

Comment: I also face this same issue in installing plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a misconfiguration or your ISP/host-provider is blocking requests

What happens if you try to manually send CURL to this address -> https://composer.craftcms.com/packages.json?